# Wrapp link in strong with replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like make a strong tag around my links in a div. These links appear dynamically.

I tried to do this :

```
$('#alertWrapp').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text()
    .replace(/#[a-z0-1A-Z]+/g, '<span style="color: #ed6567;">$&</span>')
    .replace('http://', '<strong>$&</strong>')
  );
});
```

But I can't continue the regex, it's too much complex... So it can be possible to build a regex who find the http:// protocole to space ? because it's a space who set the end of my links...

Thanks you

Comment: Why not just apply a css class?

Comment: Because I have no control over the text who is returned me... Indeed text is not ONLY url but also simple string and hashtags. This is why I need to replace just http:// to space with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just style the anchor. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5nBS/)

```
a {
font-weight: bolder;
}
```

OR

If its the url text that you want to be wrapped in bold try the following or check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9e39b/2/)

```
var text = data.replace(/https?:\/\/[^ ]+/g, '<strong>$&</strong>')
```

Comment: I thing he has links in a plain text format, without html tags

Answer (score 1):

To replace http://[anything-until-space] or https://[anything] try this

```
$('#alertWrapp').each(function() {
    $(this).html(
        $(this).text()
        .replace(/#[a-z0-1A-Z]+/g, '<span style="color: #ed6567;">$&</span>')
        .replace(/https?:\/\/[^ ]+/g, '<strong>$&</strong>')
    );
});
```